Streamed videos do not start playing automatically when using Chrome on iPhones
I've developed an interactive survey that includes videos using the VideoAsk authoring tool. The videos are set to start streaming and play automatically. This means that the user only needs to click the 'Play' button on the 1st video. All the following videos will start playing automatically when the user navigates to their respective pages.
This works as intended on Chrome on Windows PCs
It also works on Android phones (regardless of which browser is used)
It also works on Safari browser on iPhones
THE PROBLEM:
The videos do not start automatically on Chrome browser on iPhones (I tested several iPhones). Each video requires the user to click 'Play' for it to start.
How can I fix this problem? For example, can I add a line of code to the URL of the survey?
Is there any other fix or workaround?
Below is a URL to a survey that you can test on Chrome on a Windows PC (Starts automatically) versus Chrome on an iPhone (doesn't start automatically).
https://conversation.starkinsights.com/fqs8ha0z6
I launched the VideoAsk survey in Chrome on several iPhones and the videos within the survey failed to play automatically. They only played when I clicked 'Play'. I was expecting that I would only need to click 'Play' to start the 1st video and that the all the next videos would start playing without needed to click 'Play'.
